# REGEX in perl, start matching from the n occurrence of elem e

Tags: regex, perl

i need your help with some regex. I have a .csv file with fields separated with pipes and i want a regex that starts working from the n occurrence of that pipe and delete the element after including the next '|' . For Example, start from the third pipe:

```
elem1 | elem2 | elem3 | elem4 | elem5 | elem6
                  ^
```

delete result:

```
elem1 | elem2 | elem3 | elem5 | elem6
```

Hope you understand my problem. Thanks

Comment: Why use a regex for this? Read the line, split it on `|`, remove the elements from the list, then join it back together.

Comment: Anyway, you can use `{n}` after a regexp to match `n` occurrences of the pattern.

Comment: So `s/^((pattern){3})pattern/$1/` will remove the 4th occurrence of the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

[`^((?:[^|]+\|){3})[^|]+\|`](https://regex101.com/r/EkR9ms/1) (using global and multiline flags)

```
elem1 | elem2 | elem3 | elem4 | elem5 | elem6
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ group 1
                       ^^^^^^^^ included in the match
```

Replace it with `group 1`, and `elem4` will be removed. I will explain how the regex works soon.

- `^` Start of a line
- `((?:[^|]+\|){3})` A captured group

  - `(?:[^|]+\|)` 1 or more non-pipe characters, and a literal pipe character
  - `{3}` Repeat that pattern exactly 3 times
- `[^|]+` 1 or more non-pipe characters
- `\|` A literal pipe character

Answer (score 0):

You could use the global modifier `/g` and search incrementally for the Nth field. Then just delete the following field

Like this

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

my $s = 'elem1 | elem2 | elem3 | elem4 | elem5 | elem6';

$s =~ /\|/g for 1 .. 3;
$s =~ s/\G.*?\|//;

say $s;
```

#### output

```
elem1 | elem2 | elem3 | elem5 | elem6
```

But that doesn't work for the last field in the string. The tidiest way is probably to use `split` and `join`

Like this

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

my $s = 'elem1 | elem2 | elem3 | elem4 | elem5 | elem6';

$s = do {
    my @s = split /\|/, $s;
    splice @s, 3, 1;
    join '|', @s;
};

say $s;
```

The output is identical to that of the code above